# Alternative to Autohotkey to Middle click and drag on a trackpad with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, hotkeys, mouse-click, 3d-modeling

I have a typical 2017 Ultrabook, the Yoga 910. It has a trackpad with no separate buttons; bottom left portion of the trackpad is left click, bottom right is right click. There is no region of the trackpad for middle click.

This is a "precision" trackpad, so I have the native windows 10 menu for defining 2-, 3-, and 4-finger gestures. In this menu, you can define 3-finger click as being a middle mouse button click.

The problem is, I use my laptop for 3D modeling and physics simulation, and those programs (like Solidworks) make extensive use of middle-click+**drag** to perform critical functions. That behavior can be changed in Solidworks specifically, but not other software.

I know of Autohotkey but it does not seem that reliable; I also use my laptop in suburban trains where you can't always have a flat surface to put a usb mouse on, so USB mouse is not a complete solution either.

So, is there an alternative to autohotkey to emulate middle click + drag reliably in windows 10 with precision trackpads? Some 3rd party app that would replace and extend the windows 10 trackpad menu, perhaps?

As a side note, an absence of alternative here would be the single reason that might force me into buying a heavy Thinkpad P51 over a lightweight and powerful Gigabyte Aero 15X. Just, because of that missing middle mouse trackpad button. Ultrabook/Workstation manufacturers that are targeting an engineering customer base, please, dwell on that. Those trackpad buttons are just 1-2 cm3 and a few grams, they will fit, and double the workflow speed when doing 3D stuff in mobility.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I created a suggestion in the Windows Feedback Hub. Give it an upvote so Microsoft may notice it: https://aka.ms/AA3kwye